# Delete row in SQL Server only a column is zero

Tags: sql-server, triggers, calculated-columns

I have database with 2 table in SQL Server 2012.

table A

```
aid, (used), max_count
```

Table B

```
bid, aid, x
```

In table B `bid`is primary Key and `aid` is foreign key to table A.

In table A, `aid` is primary key, and `used` is computed column that count then number of used `aid` in table B.

I want in table A always `used` <= `max_count`.

How can I control update on table A that `max_count` not lower than `used`?

How can I control add to table B that `used` not greater than `max_count`?

Comment: Have you considered using a view?

Comment: Do you want to disallow the update of the table if it would create such a condition?  If so, you might need a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This triggers worked for inserting into B and updating A. You may also need other triggers for update of B.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_A 
   ON  dbo.A 
   INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM inserted
        WHERE used>max_count
    )
        RAISERROR('used cannot be higher than mox_count', 16, 1)
    ELSE
        UPDATE A SET
            A.max_count = I.max_count
        FROM A
        INNER JOIN inserted I ON I.aid = A.aid 

END;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER tr_B
   ON  dbo.B
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (
        SELECT TOP 1 A.max_count-A.used
        FROM inserted I
        INNER JOIN dbo.A ON I.aid = A.aid
    )<=0
        RAISERROR('used cannot be higher than mox_count', 16, 1)
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO dbo.B (bid, aid, x)
        SELECT bid, aid, x
        FROM inserted;
END;
GO
```